# changes in editor and rendered changes in the browser are different

Tags: css, git

I have code changes in the styles.css file, but these changes are not rendered to the browser. I cannot find these changes when this file is loaded in the browser. Has anybody had such kind of problem before?
Code change which I see in the code editor:
[image]

what is rendered styles in browser:
[image]

I cleaned page from caches but it did not help.

Comment: Is your css file is on a cdn server? Sometimes they cache the file. If you are on localhost and using chrome, open developer tools > network > check disable cache and reload

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:git]?

Comment: open developer tools > network > check disable cache and reload solved my problem. Thanks